# "All-caps posts are considered rude" popup for title without any caps

Tags: bug, questions

When typing a question title without any letters in it, Stack Exchange warns that all-caps posts are considered rude.  The warning message implies that I am proposing a title in all-caps, which is a [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).  For example:

[image: No caps]

Now, on most sites a title without any letters in them is probably not a good question.  Perhaps on puzzling one could imagine a question with a title like `2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, …?` or so.

But the warning as stated is misleading and could possibly replaced by a different warning about a poorly phrased title or something similar.

Comment: I don't believe that warning actually exists on any other sites besides Stack Overflow, so mentioning possibilities on other sites doesn't really achieve anything.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this. I see the **How to Format** window—but it doesn't mention anything about all caps. Even if it did—and a comment suggests it only appears on SO—it would only be **one item** among a list of others. Therefore, *none* of the items are specifically relevant to what you've typed. They are just general recommendations, and, therefore, appropriate.